# Is there a simpler encryption/decryption hash algorithm out there?

Tags: php, encryption, hash

I have read on this great forum and several other places how difficult, if not impossible to decrypt with md5.

Unfortunately, I used md5 to hash our users' passwords:

```
 // hash to sanitize the input further
$password = md5($password);
```

Now, I am a bit of trouble because users who cannot remember their passwords, are not able to utilize our Recover password feature.

When they attempt to recover their password, they receive the encrypted password which is useless to them because they can't use it.

Given how difficulty, almost impossible it is to decrypt an md5 hash, is there a simpler encryption / decryption mechanism that someone could suggest that I try?

Pretty much in hot water now.

Comment: No, no, no! You should secure passwords with a more secure hashing algorihm (such as PHP's built-in password_hash()/password_verify() functions), that can't be reversed; and never send passwords back to users.... password recovery should be sending them a time-limited token that permits them to reset their password without entering the old value

Comment: [Forgotten Password handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585649/php-forgot-password-function)

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Let me just say that, a **LOT** of water's gone under the bridge in over **30 years**; that's "YEARS", 360+ months. Don't use MD5 to store passwords with. Unless you want end up in the same water, **stop what you're using** if this intended to go live on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unfortunately, I used md5 to has our users' passwords

How is that *unfortunate*?  That's what you're *supposed* to do.  User passwords should be obscured behind a 1-way hash and not recoverable by *anybody*.  Not even by you as the system owner/administrator.

> users who cannot remember their passwords, are not able to utilize our Recover password feature

There should be *no such thing* as a "recover password feature".  It's called a "reset password feature".  You can *change* a user's password administratively.  But you should *never* ***ever*** be able to *read* it.

> When they attempt to recover their password, they receive the encrypted password which is useless to them because they can't use it.

But attackers ***can use it***.  Which is why you *shouldn't be sending it out to anybody in the first place*.

> is there a simpler encryption / decryption mechanism that someone could suggest that I try?

Is doesn't get much simpler than:

```
md5($password)
```

It's one function call.  Five keystrokes.  It's *really simple* to use.  And since you're already using it, you're good.

Once you stop publishing your password hashes, you'll be all set on handling user passwords (at least as far as we know here).  Keep up the great work!  There are *tons* of services out there which *don't* properly obscure user passwords.  Thank you for at least attempting it.

---

**Note:** As users have pointed out (users who are far more familiar with PHP these days than I am), while using `md5()` directly is *a step in the right direction*, it's not the best you could be doing.

Instead, take a look at PHP's built in [password handling functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).  (Or, if you're using an older, pre-5.5 version of PHP, there's a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) which maintains the same functionality.)  Jay Blanchard has written a handy article on its use [here](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

The *concept* is the same, obscuring user passwords by means of a one-way hash.  But the tooling has evolved considerably.

Comment: Well, using hashs to obscure passwords, isn't unfortunate, but using md5 instead of the password hashing api is unfortunate. :)

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @David, et al, first of all thank you all for your response.

Second, when I said unfortunately, I used md5, I was not suggesting that I should not have. I was simply suggesting that I used a far simpler approach in terms of implementation.

Because I used md5, I am finding it harder to decrypt password. If I had used another encryption method which may be a bit harder to implement but the reward of being able to decrypt using same harsh method would have been well worth the effort. That's what I was alluding to.

Comment: Also, it is rather sad that some php programmers act like they are perfect, they didn't start out learning php like me. Each time I had posted php-related questions, they come out give me massive downgrades. It doesn't change the fact that I am learning and I am trying very hard making transition from classic asp to asp.net and now to php.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh: `"the reward of being able to decrypt "` - That's not a reward, that's a bug.  And a glaring security hole which exposes user data.

Comment: @David, are you suggesting that you can encrypt but cannot unencrypt or decrypt?

Forgive me if I am screwing up here. At least you are providing constructive help and I do appreciate it.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh: The entire point of using a 1-way hash for obscuring user passwords is so that they can't be decrypted.  User passwords should never be recoverable.  If you can recover them, so can somebody else.

Comment: @David, one more thing, thank you for bringing clarity.

With your detailed explanation, it makes sense to use reset option and reuse the harsh.

Thanks so much.